# create multiple folder in jsp and some checking

Tags: jsp

I need a little help here in this situation:

1. I want to create a folder than i want to check is the folder for the current  date (folder name YYYYMMDD) is exist in the destination folder.
2. If the date folder is not exist, create the folder.
3. After the date folder is ready, perform handling on the  sub folder for window 1,2,3,4, and 5.

Need Help. Thank you

Comment: this is a project order or question, add whats your trying to do

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help with asking a great question as well as [Minimum, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).